# Any way of performing the task using python cgi?

Tags: javascript, python, onclick, cgi

I currently wrote the following task in Javascript, but I would like to execute the same task using python cgi. Do you have any tips to perform that with python cgi?

```
<a href"#" onClick="parent.Content.location='https://snu.ac.kr/music.html'; return false;">Music</a>
```

The task is basically as follows: when a user clicks the word "Music", it shows the html page (i.e.  'https://snu.ac.kr/music.html'). The reason that I would like to perform the task using python cgi is that I would like to execute other taks combining with the current task.

Would you please let me know if there is any way to perform the above task using python cgi?

Comment: What?  Javascript runs in the browser.  Python runs on the server.  The code `<a href="https://snu.ac.kr/music.html">music</a>` does what you want, and involves no Python, nor any Python CGI.  What are you really trying to do?  Do you understand the browser and server distinction in a web site?  Is that your question?

Comment: @S.Lott: Actually you are right (thus +1), but I heard [PythonFiddle.com](http://pythonfiddle.com/) runs Python within the Browser ([source](http://developers.slashdot.org/story/11/08/28/226256/Python-Fiddle-an-IDE-That-Runs-In-Your-Browser)) ;)

Comment: @Tadeck: That's not a Python CGI.  So, it can't possibly be relevant to the question. Why introduce it here?

Comment: @S.Lott: Because you said something ("_Javascript runds in the browser. Python runs on the server._") that is clearly not true when someone is aware of PythonFiddle-like solutions. And I introduced it here, because SO is for sharing knowledge, right? Btw. Javascript can also be run as server-side script (see Node.js).

Comment: @Tadeck: "SO is for sharing knowledge".  Not introducing random knowledge that's tangential to the question.  I find that it helps to focus on the question as written.  Introducing tangential knowledge means that we may as well also explain IIS even though that's not part of the question.  Since the question was about *Python CGI* -- not other Python things -- it seems better to focus on the question as written, not introduce other stray, tangential, marginally relevant ideas.   Further, your comment sounds like an answer.  Post it as such, please.

Comment: @S.Lott: I did not want to offend you, nor post the answer (because I am not sure what is asked here). The only reason I noted your comment as not fully correct, because you said something that was not true. That was my only reason. You probably meant well, but your comment was misleading. Is it clear I pointed out Python is not necessarily server-side and Javascript not necessarily client side? Hope it is. Again, please do not be offended - my intention was only to point out incorrect statement.

Comment: @Tadeck: I do get your point.  Fussy, over-the-top completeness on a *comment* is clearly very, very important to you.  Thanks for pointing that out over and over again.  I've gotten your point each time you repeated it.  Clearly, you feel that "off topic" and "not in the question" don't really apply to comments.  Got it.  Again.

Comment: @S.Lott: That was just a notice. Hope you are aware "incorrect" can also apply to comments.

Answer (score 0):

CGI is not good (as far as i read from internet) it will run a new python process everytime someone will run the script! and this is not good for your server!
maybe FastCGI is better (it will run a long single process that will handle request)